# Is there a solution that allows you to perform a task every specified number of seconds in a thread without putting it to sleep?

Tags: python, multithreading, sleep

like in questien Is there a solution that allows you to perform a task every specified number of seconds in a thread without putting it to sleep in python?

Comment: Please read [ask] and also take the [tour]. Point is, questions that suggest yes/no as answers are usually not really helpful.

Comment: FYI, also do a bit of reading on the term "XY problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1st way

You can do it useing [threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects)

```
from threading import Timer

def hello():
    print "hello, world"

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start() # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```

## 2nd way

Just check if the specific time passed. Then run `your_function()` in a thread

```
import time

current_milli_time = lambda: int(round(time.time() * 1000))

def your_function():
  last_run_millis = current_milli_time()
  while 1:
    now_millis = current_milli_time()
    delta_time = now_millis - last_run_millis
    if delta_time > 3000:
      last_run_millis = now_millis
      print("Do your stuff here")

your_function()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code runs thread1 one time after every 30 seconds:

```
import threading

def thread1:
    pass
    L1.acquire()


if "__name__" == "__main__":
    specific_time = 30
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1)
    L1 = threading.Lock(blocking=True)
    t1.start()
    init_time  = time.time()
    while 1:
        if (time.time() - init_time) >= specific_time:
            L1.release()
            init_time = time.time()
```